# PreviewKeyDown is not seeing Alt-modifiers

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some code which is (supposed to be) capturing keystrokes. The top level window has a

```
Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
```

clause and the backing CS file contains:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {
        switch (e.Key) {
            case Key.L:
                btnPrev_Click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Key.R:
                btnNext_Click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that works fine, both <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> call the relevant functions.

As soon as I change the modifer check to use `ModifierKeys.Alt`, it stops working. In other words, neither <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> call the functions.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In case of an `Alt` modifier, `e.Key` returns `Key.System` and the real key is in `e.SystemKey`. You can use the following piece of code to always get the correct pressed key:

```
Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
```

Answer (score 63):

The trouble is that when Alt is held down your KeyEventArgs has:

```
Key = Key.System
SystemKey = the real key
```

so when checking for Alt you need to use e.SystemKey instead of e.Key, like this:

```
if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt) {   
    switch (e.SystemKey) { 
      ...
```

**Explanation**

Under Windows, the "Alt" key is handled specially.  When the Alt key itself is pressed or another key is pressed while the Alt key is held down, it is considered a "System" keypress.  "System" keypresses are handled differently than regular keypresses in many ways.

It all starts out when Windows passes the keypress to your application.  Normal key down events generate a WM_KEYDOWN, but if the Alt key is pressed it generates a WM_SYSKEYDOWN.  By the same token a WM_KEYUP is translated into a WM_SYSKEYUP.

Throughout Windows, including in WPF, the special handling of the Alt key is used with MenuItems, Buttons and Labels that include "access text".  For example, if a button has content of "Say _Hi", then presing Alt-H will be treated as a a button click.

When the Alt key is down, letters come in as three pairs of events:  KeyDown, KeyUp and TextInput, each with their associated preview versions.  The primary differences here are:

- The KeyDown and KeyUp events have their Key property set to "Key.System" rather than the actual key that was pressed, and the SystemKey set to the actual key pressed.
- The TextInput event is passed normally but then handled as an AccessKey if it is not consumed

Comment: Thanks, Ray, the explanation was an added bonus so +1 for that.

Comment: Excellent explanation! +1 for you Sir

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the ALT key handling.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Julien. I'd been bashing my head against this for at least a couple of hours.