# Detecting modifier key down?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to respond when a modifier key (e.g. Alt or Control) is first pressed. The response needs to occur regardless of whether or not other keys are pressed at the same, so I basically need to be able to tell the instant any of those keys goes down.

The eventing behavior that I'm seeing for modifier keys is different than other keys --- it looks like the KeyDown event and PreviewKeyDown events actually fire when the button comes UP after being pressed, which isn't helpful.

While digging into the event firing issue, I created a timed background loop that polls all of the current key states. Even that isn't working --- if I press down a modifier key, and I don't release the key or press any other keys, this poll incorrectly says that the modifier key is not actually down (indefinitely, until another key gets pressed)

I feel like I must be missing something basic, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Check Ray Burns explanation in that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099472/previewkeydown-is-not-seeing-alt-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Are you attaching to the "Keyboard.KeyDown" event on your main Window instance?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Keyboard.KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">

</Window>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried attaching both KeyDown and PreviewKeyDown handlers. They are firing, just not when I need them to. The events occur either: a) when the modifier key comes back up after being pressed, or b) when another key on the keyboard gets pressed down. Just pressing down the modifier doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I noticed in your original post that you were using a timer to test this, you should know that the WPF timer is thread safe, meaning it will not fire until the UI completes execution.  Try just putting a MessageBox in your keydown handler and see when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this behavior is specific to my environment (running Windows & Visual Studio in a Parallels 6.0 VM). Parallels must be intercepting these events to preserve some low-level Mac OS functionality. I'm not sure about other VM setups, but this looks like a non-issue in native Windows environments.