# can not move the image having focus on textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to move the image using `control key + arrows`  which is in grid having the focus on textbox.

Below code in KeyDownEvent:

```
  if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
  {
      if (e.SystemKey == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Up ||
          e.SystemKey == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Down ||
          e.SystemKey == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Right ||
          e.SystemKey == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Left)
          {
                if (ImagePreviewActions.KeyDownAction != null)
                {
                    ImagePreviewActions.KeyDownAction.Invoke(e);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
          }


  <local:ImagePreview  x:Name="imgPreview_Credit"

                    ImageSource="{Binding SelectedCreditImage.Image, Mode=OneWay}"
                    EnableKeyEvents="False"
                    EnableCrop="False"
                    EnableZoom="True"
                    FitImageToControl="True"
                    FunGetCroppedImageInBytes="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.FunGetCroppedImageInBytes, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    ImageCropCompletedAction="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.ImageCropCompletedAction, Mode=OneWay}"
                    KeyAction="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.KeyDownAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    ScrollViewStyle="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerStyle}"
                    Width="935.342" Height="273"

                    ZoomAction="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.ZoomAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    RotateAction="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.RotateAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    ResetAndFitImageAction="{Binding CreditImagePreviewActions.ResetAndFitImageAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"                                                                       

                    />
```

ImagePreview is the custom control below is the code for it
xaml--

```
     <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Smi.Smart.Common.UI.Controls"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImagePreview}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImagePreview}">

                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_spanel"  
                        Width="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        Height="{Binding Path=Height,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <ScrollViewer Name="PART_scrl"   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

                      Style="{Binding ScrollViewStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Width="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        Height="{Binding Path=Height,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              CanContentScroll="True">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PART_canvasForImage"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=CanvasVerticalAlignment,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 

                                >
                                <Image x:Name="PART_imageDisplay" 
                               Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TranslateTransform />
                                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="PART_imageDisplayScaleTransform"/>
                                            <RotateTransform />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Line x:Name="PART_ruler" X1="0" Y1="100" X2="300" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but it is showing as none in system key

Comment: What's none .? 
post XAML with your Grid with the image and textbox.

Comment: above is the xaml code

Comment: value at system key was shown as none while dbugging

Comment: I'm sorry it's nearly impossible to understand the scenario .
who handles the key event ?, where are the textbox and image located ?
what's an ImagePreview control.. 
No one would be able to help you like this , you must think of a minimal scenario outside your control , build some sort of tester aside from it and try to do what ever it is your trying to do . And find out if a concrete problem exists.

Comment: i have added ImagePreview custom control xaml file

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to understand from your code example what exactly you try to achieve or more precisely how you are trying to achieve it

The reason the value is "None" is because the control key and the arrows keys are not system keys.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100000/1195341

Comment: still its not working as i expected arrow key values are not passed

Comment: may i know difference between PreviewKeyDown Event and keydown event